# scheme check-expect output record combined with record-procedures

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket, record

i am currently programming in scheme and i have written the following record-procedures that records a creature (= kreatur in German) with the character traits strength (= stärke), knowledge (= wissen) and readiness to assume a risk (= risikobereitschaft), i defined two creatures named "ronugor" and "garnolaf" (the names are not my idea, its from a exercise i didn't come up with ;) ) and then i wrote a procedure to mix the character traits of these two creatures (strengh -5%, knowledge unchanged, readiness to assume a risk still 0) to receive a new creature named "ronulaf".

this is my code:

```
    (: stärke (kreatur -> number))
    (: wissen (kreatur -> number))
    (: risikobereitschaft (kreatur -> number))
    (define-record-procedures kreatur
      make-kreatur
      kreatur?
      (stärke
       wissen
      risikobereitschaft))


   ; check-property (i kept this out of the posted code to shorten it)


    ;define the creatures garnolaf and ronugor
    (: make-kreatur (number number number -> kreatur))
    (define garnolaf
       (make-kreatur 100 0 0))

    (: make-kreatur (number number number -> kreatur))
    (define ronugor
       (make-kreatur 0 100 0))


    ;signaturen
    (: garnolaf? (kreatur -> boolean))
    (check-expect (garnolaf? garnolaf) #t)
    (check-expect (garnolaf? ronugor) #f)
    (define garnolaf?
       (lambda (x)
          (and (= (stärke x) 100)
               (= (wissen x) 0)
               (= (risikobereitschaft x) 0))))

     (: ronugor? (kreatur -> boolean))
     (check-expect (ronugor? garnolaf) #f)
     (check-expect (ronugor? ronugor) #t)
     (define ronugor?
       (lambda (x)
          (and (= (stärke x) 0)
               (= (wissen x) 100)
               (= (risikobereitschaft x) 0))))


     ;mixing of the creatures
     (: ronulaf (kreatur kreatur -> kreatur))
     ;this is where i am missing a check-expect, i suppose
     (define ronulaf
       (lambda (r g)
          (make-kreatur (* 0.95 (stärke g))
                        (wissen r)
                         0)))
```

the question i now have is how i can write a check-expect for the procedure ronulaf. i would write is somehow like this:

```
    (check-expect (ronulaf ronugor garnolaf) #<record:kreatur 95.0 100 0>)
```

but it doesn't work. does anybody have a better idea for a check-expect?

thanks already!
eva

Answer (score 0):

Notice how your `garnolaf?` and `ronugor?` procedures are written? Now write something similar for `ronulaf`. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 (check-expect (ronulaf ronugor garnolaf) (make-kreatur 95 100 0))
```

Not all objects representations can be feed into read and become that object. #< in the beginning makes it look like an evaluated procedure and it's the same for those.

Comment: Thank for your answer first of all :) However, if I try that I receive the following error:
check-expect encountered the following error instead of the expected value, #<record:kreatur 95 100 0>.

Like I said above in my post #<record:kreatur 95 100 0> does not work either though...

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct language from DeinProgramm? In a Racket language you would have used [struct](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html?q=struct&q=rackunit&q=unit&q=define-record-procedures#%28form._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fbase..rkt%29._struct%29%29) and [rackunit](http://docs.racket-lang.org/rackunit/api.html?q=rackunit&q=unit&q=define-record-procedures)

Comment: I am using "DeinProgramm, Die Macht der Abstraktion - Anfänger" which would be translated to "DeinProgramm, the power of abstraction - beginners". It is the first option under "DeinProgramm". I don't know if it is the right language but its the one we have to use for college...

Comment: It's the correct one. I think I have found your problem: `(check-expect (make-kreatur 95.0 100 0) (make-kreatur 95.0 100 0))` fails. It might be a problem with `check-expect`. `(check-expect (make-kreatur 95 100 0) (make-kreatur (/ (* 100 95) 100) 100 0))` passes so it has something against inexact values when in records even when their inexact values are `equal?`

Comment: It actually does have to do with inexact values - that is what I figured too. I tried what you said with "check-within" instead and that worked. Thank you!